# ReactJs style table row from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to style the background of my tr if a prop is present:

I am passing the prop here in one of my columns:

```
<Column highlightRow="yes" />
```

Here is my table row render:

```
 render: function () {

   var columns = this.props.columns;
   var data = this.props.data;
   //loop through columns looking for prop
   var styleCheck =  columns.map(function (column) {
        if (column.props.highlightRow) {

            var styles = {
                backgroundColor: 'pink'
            };
        }
    });

    return (
        <tr style={styles}>
            {this.getCellNodes()}
        </tr>
    );

}
```

I keep getting the error `styles is not defined`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: instead of `highlightRow="yes"` better to use `highlightRow={ true }`. Because when you (or somebody else) do `highlightRow="no"` the result will be the same as with 'yes'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to scope the `styles` variable so it can be seen:

```
render: function () {

   var columns = this.props.columns;
   var data = this.props.data;
   var styles = {};
   //loop through columns looking for prop
   var styleCheck =  columns.map(function (column) {
        if (column.props.highlightRow) {

            styles = {
                backgroundColor: 'pink'
            };
        }
    });

    return (
        <tr style={styles}>
            {this.getCellNodes()}
        </tr>
    );

}
```

Besides that, currently, if `highlightRow` is set to any string, it will be truthy.